# Sum multiple list elements using linq

Tags: c#, list, linq, sum

I am trying to generate a class containing summary values using LINQ.

I have a List which contains a List.
My return should be 1 MasterClass object with List containing the value summary.

```
MasterClass:                                      Example data
        public string A { get; set; }             "1"  "1"  subclass(below)
        public string B { get; set; }             "1"  "2"  subclass(below)
        public List<subClass> list { get; set; }  "2"  "3"  subclass(below)

subClass:                                      Example data(for each master)
        public DateTime date { get; set; }      29/01/2018  10  5  20
        public int NetChange { get; set; }      29/01/2018  20 10  30
        public int Shares { get; set; }         30/01/2018   5 10  20
        public int HeldPerc { get; set; }       31/01/2018  10  5  10
                                                31/01/2018  10  5  20
                                                31/01/2018  10  5  30
```

what i want is to get a summary of all subclasses that have master.A="1".
(in this case 2 masterclasses combined into one calculating the total values of the subclass grouped by date)

```
Master:(this part i can already achieve)
"1" "1/2" subclass(below) 

subclass:(summed up values of both individual subclasses grouped by date)
29/01/2018 60 30 100
30/01/2018 10 20 40
31/01/2018 60 30 120
```

How can i achieve this calculation

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What types are A and b from MasterClass? Are A and b related to the question? What do you mean by summary? The example data you provided is not accurate. Please improve your question and we might be able to answer it.

Comment: Do you also have a list of MasterClass?

Comment: Providing the example in *code* in the form of a [mcve] would really help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then here is what you need to do:

```
masterClassList
    .Where(mc => mc.A == "1")
    .SelectMany(mc => mc.SubClasses)
    .GroupBy(sc => sc.Date)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Date = g.Key,
        NetChange = g.Sum(sc => sc.NetChange),
        Shares = g.Sum(sc => sc.Shares),
        HeldPerc = g.Sum(sc => sc.HeldPerc),
    });
```

Here is a working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/uO0Mxn.

Comment: That's what i was looking for thank you!